# Magento becomes unresponsive / hangs while trying to save config in System > Configuration > Payment methods

Tags: configuration, payment, methods

currently i have two payment methods for my site .
cash on delivery is working fine.
but when i try to make payment using payumoney. then after placing the order it should redirect to payumoney website for final payment . but it gets redirected to shopping cart.

one more problem has arised 
when i go to System > Configuration > Payment methods
and make some changes . say activate or deactivate some payment methods and hit save config the that page becomes unresponsive & struck for sometime but other tabs work fine .moreover the changes never gets saved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling payumoney. It seems to be calling somewhere to authenticate your access tokens and it hangs up because of this while saving payment methods. Then contact the extension developers and ask them about this issue, we cannot help you here without seeing the extension code.

Comment: i tried disabling it still it hangs up while saving and making some changes in System > Configuration > Payment methods